# Concatenate a strings received from command line arguments in BATCH

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch

I have a batch file that fills couple of variables received from command line argument and I would like to concatenate these variables:

```
@echo off

:GETOPTS
if /I "%1" == "-d" set DIR1=%2 & shift
if /I "%1" == "-a" set DIR2=%2 & shift
shift
if not "%1" == "" goto GETOPTS

set DIR3=%DIR1%\%DIR2%
echo %DIR3%
```

Now when I execute it, see this:

```
>dir.bat -d abc -a xyz

abc \xyz
```

But would like it to be like abc\xyz

**EDIT:**

I tried making it work using this:

```
set DIR1=%DIR1%##
set DIR1=%DIR1: ##=##%
set DIR1=%DIR1:##=%
```

But @Akina solution is far-2 better.

Comment: `if /I "%1" == "-d" set DIR1=%2&&shift` and the same for next line.

Comment: This is your third post about this script of 8 lines. Surely you can figure something out or search it out. Hint: There is another post here with exactly the same subject.

Comment: Sorry @harrymc just started to learn BATCH , tried to make it work in parallel and found some solution using substitution but looking for best solution to this problem.

Comment: @Akina, Thanks , it worked.

Comment: Our website is not a support forum for students. Please try to find your own solution, search, try things etc, just as we all did once. We don't expect so many posts by one person about one subject, especially a subject for which exist hundreds of thousands of posts on the internet.